# load GridView from sql source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-binding, gridview

I'm trying to load my gridview (which I'm new at) and I'm a bit lost. The thing I want to do is to create a column header manually called "Description" and get all other column header from a sql dataset of my table DocumentTypes (dataset1).

The column "Description" needs to get all the content from the table "Literature" (dataset2).
All the other columns needs to get all content (if there's some) from the table "Documents" (dataset3)

Here's where I'm stuck.
This is what i do for creating manually my first column header. I want this column to have all informations from dataset2.

```
BoundField m_bfBoundField = new BoundField();
m_bfBoundField.HeaderText = "Description";
m_bfBoundField.DataField = "Name";
gridView.Columns.Add(m_bfBoundField);
```

Then i do

```
gridView.DataSource = dataset2;
gridView.DataBind();
```

I tried the same thing for getting my headers from datasource1 but without putting the .DataField for now (do I need one for my relations?)

Actually, this is getting all the "Name" column from datasource2 and load it to the "Description" column but it also display a "Name" column in my grid with the same info :(.

What's wrong and how can I do that? Is that clear?

I would like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Description (can be called as I want) | Manuals (data from dataset1) | Catalog (data from dataset1) |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DescripionA (data from dataset2)      | Yes (data from dataset3)     | No (data from dataset3)      |
| DescripionB (data from dataset2)      | No (data from dataset3)      | Yes(data from dataset3)      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This might be a pain in the ass but the only way I know how to do this would be to set this in the gridview

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

and then make databound items for all your columns. If you want the column header to be the same as the dataset column name just dont set the HeaderText in the new boundField();

you can do this directly on the .aspx page like so

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="NONOPSgridviewDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <!-- These are the boundedfields of the rest of your dataset -->
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Lastname" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add new column to your data source ?
Or Can you copy your data-source to your new datatable and in new datatable add new column.
After that bind that datatable as datasource to your grid.
Good way to edit your data source is because if you do reordering data in your grid description may not be as you liked if they are not stacked in data source.